# Master theorem. Particular example I can't understand

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science

I thought that I understood how to use the Master Theorem but apparently I don't.
So here it is:

```
     T(n) = 16 T(n/2) +2(n^4)
     T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n^c)
     a=16 
     b=2
     log base b of a = log base 2 of 16 = 4 
     c = 4
```

c and log base b of a are equal to each other, I think that this is the 2nd case of the master theorem. So big Theta should be (n^4 log n) but everybody says it's n^4.

I can't understand where I've gone wrong. 
Could somebody please explain it to me.

Comment: I agree with you; it should be $T(n) = \Theta(n^4 \log n)$.

Comment: @Caroline Welcome to math stack exchange!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Using the [Master Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CVBS.png)
, **$\frac{\log_{2}\left(16\right)}{\log_{2}\left(2\right)}=4=c$** thus **$T(n) = \Theta(f(n) \log n)$**. Therefore **$T(n) = \Theta(n^4 \log n)$**.